# How to let program wait for task done then exit after click close botton

Tags: c#, multithreading

As the title shows, how to let my program wait for something finish then exit after click the close botton.

I have to make sure some important task has been finished so i can let the program exit. but i have no idea about how to do it.

I tried to create a flag like this:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public bool closeable = true;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
         public setCloseable()
         {
             this.closeable = false;
         }
    }
```

In the other thread, when my program is doing something very important,i set the "closeable" to false after the task finished ,set the closeable to true;
when the use click the close button, i use this code:

```
private void MainForm_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.closeable == true)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

This didn't work because if the value is not true when use click close.then the program will not close.

Is this way right? How should I improve it or any suggestion?

Comment: u can use backgroudworker or using task and eventwaithandles.

Comment: how to ,can you give me some demo?

Comment: here is for backgroundworker - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.100).aspx - and here for eventwaithandles - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx

Comment: You could use TPL with WaitAll http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235699.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your code as it is, but you will have to assign `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel` to `True` in your closing handler to avoid the program from closing if it shouldn't.

What you should add is a `Timer` in your closing handler that only starts if you are running your task AND if it isn't started already. This timer runs every second or five seconds or whatever you deem is a good amount.  The timer's job is to check to see if your task has finished and if it has it will set your `closeable` field to true and fire the `Close` event in your program.

Then, your `FormClosing` event will fire, see that `closeable` is `True` and it will then not set `FormClosingEventArgs.Cancel` to true and will allow the program to exit.

```
Timer timer1 = null;
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    timer1 = new Timer();
    timer1.Interval = (int)new TimeSpan(0, 0, 4).TotalMilliseconds;
    timer1.Tick += (s, ev) => { timer1.Stop();  closeable = IsTaskDone(); Close(); };
}

public bool closeable = true;
public void setCloseable()
{
    this.closeable = false;
}

private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.closeable == true)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        timer1.Start();

        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}

private bool IsTaskDone()
{
    // TODO: returns true if the task is completed
}
```

Comment: great, how can't i did't think about timer! haha great i was think about start a new thread.but you solved my problem .thinks a lot!

Comment: But wait, this also could happen, when use click close . task is running and when the task finished unfortunately, a new task is start again, what worse when the timer check the closeable ,it was false,but when task finished ,timer didn't check........ wow a bad situation

Comment: I personally don't like the timer way, also because timers and windows may lead to memory leaks when no properly managed.

Let's say that the above one is very specific to *your* case, but just in case having more windows you'll get a pain...

Comment: and by the way.now i have another class. in this class i want to set the closeable without new a MainForm how to do it?

Comment: @JasonYang, I've updated my code example. This would be better to watch for new tasks to startup. Also, you could reduce the interval.

Comment: @BradRem thinks for you code but i have another question i had commented above

Comment: @JasonYang, I'm thinking that Mario might be a cleaner solution, especially if you need to keep track of multiple tasks in multiple classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.canceleventargs.cancel.aspx) property. Setting it to `true` will cancel the closing of the form.

```
bool hasUserClickedClose = false;
private void MainForm_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.closeable)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; 
        hasUserClickedClose = true;
    }
}
```

Then after your other method has completed its task.

```
if(hasUserClickedClose)
{
   this.closeable = true;
   Application.Exit();
}
```

Comment: this just let the program can't close when there is a important task.i need it exit after this task finished!

Comment: I thought that was the point? You don't want the application to close while it's doing important work.

Comment: but it should close when this task finished. as your code goes, when this task finished ,the use should click close again!i don't want the use click the close button again.

Comment: Can you not just set a variable if the user clicks the close button and then check this variable after your method is completed?

Answer (score 0):

The KeyboardP way is correct, and I think it's also the simplest. However, my suspect is that you're expecting something smarter.

You could create a special singleton class. Instead having the "closeable" flag in the MainForm, just place a "importantTasksCount" of type integer.

Every time an important task starts, you should increment that counter, and decrement it once the task terminates.

The singleton pattern simplifies the access to the controller instance from everywhere.

Now, here's the trick:

```
// Winforms/WPF version
public sealed class CloseManager
{
  private CloseManager(){}
  private static CloseManager _instance;
  public static CloseManager Instance
  {
    get 
    { 
      if (_instance == null) _instance = new CloseManager();
      return _instance;
    }
  }


  private static bool closeable;
  private static int importantTasksCount;

  public static void CloseRequest()
  {
    this.closeable = true;
  }

  public static void IncImportantTask()
  {
    this.importantTasksCount++;
  }

  public static void DecImportantTask()
  {
    this.importantTasksCount--;
    if (this.closeable) Application.Exit();
  }

}
```

Comment: why use singleton pattern?

Comment: I suggest a singleton because the requested function is global (i.e. exit the app) and it's easy to access from everywhere in the app.

The user hadn't specified who are the responsible for the "important" tasks, thus a singleton should be pretty neutral. Moreover, I would be unaware from thinking that there's only one MainForm: an app might open several windows.

Comment: is your code a singleton , it seems  not .can you edit it again?

Comment: Shouldn't this class or at least the counter field be made static?

Comment: Okay, I understood: my example was referred to WPF, but it's not so different in the Winforms world.

Let me edit the source...

Comment: @bradRen Here is the problem , this class should be static and when it is static,Application.exit can't exit the programe, what should i do?

Comment: @Jason: Why the program shouldn't halt calling "Application.Exit()" inside a static class?

Comment: no it did not. Console.WriteLine("exit");
                Application.Exit(); it print the exit but not exit

Comment: If won't exit, it means that there is some thread still running: check for it!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34326/discussion-between-mario-vernari-and-jason-yang)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the heavy work on the `importantTask` Task, but it is a little ugly from the user perspective to do that. From what you said you want, this should work:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
 {
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.importantTask= Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{/*do your work*/});
    }
    private Task importantTask;

    private async void MainForm_closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
         await importantTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , but this code is hard to read.and the important task is not only one. so i do not think this is a good solution.but thanks again